# Removing Padding between hamburger and Title

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I would like to remove left padding in ActionBar between the hamburger & the title without having to use toolbars. I tried toolbars but i have encountered limitations that i felt were drawbacks.
I am new in Android programming and would appreciate a clean solution to this using the default ActionBar.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this use below property of toolbar**

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

now set you `toolbar` like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" />

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    // add here all your controlls
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**now set toolbar in activity like this**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**ask me in case of any query**

Comment: thanks for the reply. Kinly expound on the following         app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"

Comment: @jmsiox didn't get you..?

Comment: Am stuck at adding the styles for the toolbar as my text is now not visible after changing to toolbar..

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what i wanted.